# Shorter way of doing x.present? ? x : z

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This is really starting to look repetitive and bulky when I do something like:

```
Name: <%= @user.name.present? ? @user.name : "Unknown" %>
```

I know I can do `@user.name || "Unknown"` but that doesn't handle empty strings as far as i know.

Is there a shorter approach?

Comment: You are possibly looking for `.empty?` but sure Rails has something added in to enhance that. :)

Comment: Just for your information, only `nil` and `false` are evaluated as false in boolean expressions, ie. empty string is `true`.

Answer (score 6):

```
<%= @user.name.presence || "Unknown" %>
```

From the Rails official documentation:

> **presence()**
>
> Returns object if it’s present? otherwise returns nil. object.presence is equivalent to object.present? ? object : nil.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-presence

Answer (score 0):

You could add a helper method

```
def view_name( user, default="Unknown" )
  user.name.present? ? @user.name : default
end
```

so that your view is just :

```
Name: <%= view_name( @user ) %>
```